# Azure AD B2C Internal Error uploading Custom Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am experiencing an issue where a set of custom policies that upload without issue to one tenant (development tenant), fail to upload to another (production tenant). The policies function correctly on the (working) development tenant.

[image]

I upload the files in the following order:

1. TrustFrameworkBase.xml **uploads OK**
2. TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml **uploads OK**
3. SignUpOrSignin.xml **fails with above error**
4. ProfileEdit.xml **fails with above error**
5. PasswordReset.xml **uploads OK**

The only clue I have is that if I query the extension claims in the B2C app for the failing tenant, it only shows 2 out of 8. If I run the same query against the working tenant, it shows all 8. I am doing this querying using this example app: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet.

As far as I can tell, the two tenants are configured the same, and I have checked the various IDs etc are configured correctly. But it is always possible I have missed something!

Can anyone help?

The xml files: https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApxUZQaL9hp0h1ACYgWzgzsGwCOc

**More info**

I can actually run the policies that upload with an error. But when I try to create an user account via running the policy I get a message saying "Unable to validate the information provided." at the top of the page, inside the `<div>` with the id `claimVerificationServerError`. This may tie-up with the missing extension claims in the B2C app. So it looks like the problem is with creating the extension claims. But the same policy uploads and works on another tenant. How could the extension claims be valid on one tenant, but not on another?

Comment: Can you upload failing policy? remove all sensitive info and upload

Comment: I'll try, thanks. I just gave it a go and it exceeded the character limit... I'll see if I can link to it somewhere.

Comment: I guess you can upload file just upload in your question

Comment: I have linked to the documents inside the question.

Comment: I can't see policies there, can you recheck?

Comment: Odd - I can see them from a browser on a separate computer. Let me know if you still can't see them. Cheers

Comment: I can see policies now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your base policy, there is the following claim of dateOfBirth:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_DateOfBirth">
    <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
    <DataType>date</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Date of birth</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
    <PredicateValidationReference Id="DateOfBirthDateRange" />
</ClaimType>
```

Since this claim starts with "extension_" and it is used in a technical profile with "AAD-" as prefix, it will be automatically created as an extension attribute in AAD during the policy uploading. However, the DataType "date" is not supported (only DateTime is supported) in AAD. This is causing policy uploading failure.

Regarding how to map "date" claim in B2C policy to AAD "DateTime" attribute, I will reply back to this thread after more investigation on these policies is done.

Edit: I was trying to find this doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#extensionproperty-entity when I first replied but could not find it. Thanks Mat for sharing. Hope this link is helpful for solving issues related to datatype of extension attributes in AAD.

Comment: In case it is useful for anyone, the custom policy schema allows the type `date` under `<xs:simpleType name="DataType">`. See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd. Whereas the Azure AD Graph API does not, see `dataType` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#extensionproperty-entity.

Comment: Thanks Yin - great answer. You are correct. I just tried changing the `DataType` to `dateTime` and I was able to upload the policy without error. However, when running the policy, the sign-up page froze after hitting "Create" and never continued. The user was created in the B2C directory though. I changed the DataType back to `date` - and now I can upload the policy without error, and run the policy. Weird! I think this must be how my dev tenant was working.Thank you for your effort - I find pouring over these XML files a real brain-ache!

Comment: Glad to see it is working for your tenant now although it is indeed weird. I think the reason here is that failure related to dataType date only happens for the first time creating this attribute in AAD. Once it got created, you can change it from DateTime to Date during the following uploading. There is no failure due to no attribute-creating behavior. Regarding the froze sign-up page, the reason may be that currently the userInputType DateTimeDropdown only works with dataType Date (I know it looks wrong). I will see what I can do for it.

Answer (score 0):

Extension attributes need to be created at a per tenant basis. So if your policy requires extension attributes, you need to create them explicitly.

Comment: When I upload my custom policies, the extension attributes are created automatically on the B2C extensions app. As per Yin's answer.